# Angular 2.4.9- How to correctly downgrade to 2.4.8

Tags: angular

I looked through everything and can't understand how to downgrade @angular/core to 2.4.8

I got install @angular/cli with version 1.0.0-rc.0 as 1.0.0-rc.1 is buggy.
Now would like to downgrade the core also as it has also bugs that I can seem to fix.

Here is ng -v

```
Chriss-iMac:dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1 christarasovs$ ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/


 @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
node: 7.7.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/cli: error
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
```

Thank you for taking you time to look into it.

Pacakage.json

```
{
  "name": "dnd-2.4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.0.0-rc.1.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  },
   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: remove and add again? `npm rm @angular/core`

Comment: Can you provide contents of your `package.json`? Or at least the lines with Angular packages?

Comment: Added, I have manually changed 2.4.8 to 2.4.9.

Comment: Thank you. This file is used as NPM’s configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to stick with 2.4.8, you should change `^2.4.8` to `2.4.8` and then run `npm install`. That’s because using *caret dependency* you’ll always get newest package from 2.* range.